# how to populate the data from table which unmapped column in join

Tags: mysql, database, join

I am having below tables and want to populate the PAYID from the PAY table by looking in to CATEGORY_ID for below use case

1. if PAYID is mapped with CATEGORY_ID then return the PAYID
2. if PAYID is not mapped to CATEGORY_ID then look for BILL_ID and populate is by joining the NETWORK_CATEGORY and CATEGORY table.
3. If PAYID is not mapped to CATEGORY_ID and even BILL_ID is not associated with NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID then return the CATEGORY_ID as 3 (Uncategorized) for PAY.

Below is the my tables,

PAY Table

```
PAYID   BILL_ID  CATEGORY_ID
101       1        1
102       2 
103       3
```

BILL Table

```
BILL_ID      NAME    NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID
1            ABC          42
2            XYZ    
3            DSC          23
```

NETWORK_CATEGORY Table

```
NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID  NAME    CATEGORY_ID
42                   Electric/gas   1
23                   ISP    2
```

CATEGORIES

```
CATEGORY_ID  NAME
1            Utilities
2            Telecom
3            Uncategorized
```

And i have written below queries ,

```
select payid(
        select payid from PAY p
        where p.CATEGORY_ID in (:categoryIds)
    UNION
        select payid from PAY p 
            join BILLS b on p.BILL_ID = b.BILL_ID 
        where NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID in 
            (
                select NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID 
                from NETWORK_CATEGORY nc 
                    join CATEGORIES c on nc.CATEGORY_ID = c.CATEGORY_ID 
                where c.CATEGORY_ID in (:categoryIds)
            )
            and CATEGORY_ID is null 
        )
```

My expectation is that if i passed the categoryIds as 3 or (1,2,3 )then it should return the PAYID as 102 and 101,102,103 respectively.
How can i do that.
Or i can say that how can achieve this task,

If PAYID is not mapped to CATEGORY_ID and even BILL_ID is not associated with NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID then return the CATEGORY_ID as 3 (Uncategorized) for PAY.

By using three union i can achieve that but that not looks an efficient solution.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Well there is no `PAY.CATEGORY_ID` with the value of `3` in your data example

Comment: @RiggsFolly its there in CATEGORY tables. IF its not present in PAY table then its not mapped to any category_id then return the CATEGORY_ID as 3.

Comment: 'if i passed the categoryIds as 3 then it should return the PAYID as 102 - I don't see how given 102 does not have a category id of 3 in pay..

Comment: No thats a BILL_ID in your data sample

Comment: But it still doesn't map to 102

Comment: In PAY table its not present, if PAY table doesnt contains then i need to look in to the BIll for NETWORK_CATEGORIES if its still not there then use it from CATEGORY table.

Comment: @P.Salmon its not necessary that every payid has the category_id. as per my current requirement if PAY_ID doesn't contain the CATEGORY_ID then i will have to look in to BILL table and from there by using the NETWORK_CATEGORY find the CATEGORY_ID and return. if BILL table network_id is also not mapped then return the CATEGORY_ID as 3(Uncategorized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.PAYID
FROM PAY p
WHERE p.CATEGORY_ID IN (2,3)

UNION ALL

SELECT p.PAYID
FROM PAY p
JOIN BILL b
    ON p.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL AND p.BILL_ID = b.BILL_ID
JOIN NETWORK_CATEGORY nc
    ON b.NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID = nc.NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID
WHERE nc.CATEGORY_ID IN (2,3)

UNION ALL

SELECT p.PAYID
FROM PAY p
LEFT JOIN BILL b
    ON p.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL AND p.BILL_ID = b.BILL_ID
LEFT JOIN NETWORK_CATEGORY nc
    ON b.NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID = nc.NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID
WHERE (3 IN (2,3) AND p.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL AND nc.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL)
```

Depending on the size of the dataset and the other criteria being applied to the `PAY` table, this may perform OK -

```
SELECT p.PAYID
FROM PAY p
LEFT JOIN BILL b
    ON p.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL AND p.BILL_ID = b.BILL_ID
LEFT JOIN NETWORK_CATEGORY nc
    ON b.NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID = nc.NETWORK_CATEGORY_ID
WHERE p.CATEGORY_ID IN (2,3)
  OR nc.CATEGORY_ID IN (2,3)
  OR (3 IN (2,3) AND p.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL AND nc.CATEGORY_ID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Messy but 1) first subquery (x) to cater for no entries, 2) first part of union to check category id, 3) UNION to deal with situation where bill_id and category_id are the same, 4) second part of union to find pay via bill, 5) coalesce to cater for no entries.

```
select coalesce(payid,3) payid,s.`bill/category id` 
from
(select 2 `bill/category id` ) x
left join 
(select payid ,category_id as `bill/category id` from pay where category_id = 2
union
select payid ,bill.bill_id
from bill 
join network_category nc on bill.network_category_id = nc.network_category_id
join pay  on pay.bill_id = nc.category_id
where bill.bill_id = 2
      and not exists (select payid from pay where category_id = 2)
) s on s.`bill/category id` = x.`bill/category id`
```

Comment: in the query of my question (:categoryIds)  its list of category id so suppose if i will pass the category id as (2,3) then it should return me payid 102,103. above query wont work